# Assignment to constant within body of method

Tags: ruby, constants

"The Ruby Programming Language" by David Flanagan & Yukihiro Matsumoto states the following in Section 4.5.2 Assigning to Constants

> Assignment to constants is not allowed within the body of a method.

I understand the premise and try two variations of code:

```
PERSONS = {}

def create_persons(filename)
  File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, number|
    array = line.split(' ').unshift(number+1)
    hash = {:id => array[0],:first_name => array[1], :last_name => array[2], :email => array[3]}
    PERSONS = hash
  end
end
```

I get an error:

```
santa.rb:13: dynamic constant assignment
    PERSONS = hash
             ^
```

The I try second version, where instead of assigning using the equal operator, I initialize an empty array as constant and use the append operator to append hash to empty array. This works!

```
PERSONS = []

def create_persons(filename)
  File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, number|
    array = line.split(' ').unshift(number+1)
    hash = {:id => array[0],:first_name => array[1], :last_name => array[2], :email => array[3]}
    PERSONS << hash
  end
end
```

My question is why does the second version work when I use the << assignment operator, but does not work with = assignment operator.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You're not assigning to or redefining the constant--you're doing something to the object *referenced* by that constant. Nitpick: `<<` isn't any sort of assignment, it's a method.

Comment: @dave-newton << did appear to be like a method to me too, i.e., it appends. But in the same Ruby book I referenced above, it shows the following examples as abbreviated assignments: x <<= y (x = x << y) and x >>= y (x = x >> y). This is adding to my confusion.

Comment: Ok, @DaveNewton. I get your comment now and understand the difference between assigning (changing the object reference) and modifying the object referenced by the constant (reference is to the same object, but modified). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odd thing about constants in Ruby is you can *define* them once, but modify them endlessly unless they're frozen. The first one is a problem because you're switching which object `PERSONS` refers to. In the second case you're adding something to an existing object, this is allowed.

Technically it's possible to redefine constants but this is best avoided.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's odd at all. I think most, or at least many, OOP-ish languages with mutable objects behave similarly.

Comment: Say compared to `const` in other languages. They're barely "constant" in Ruby!

Comment: That's what I mean. Apart from Ruby's very odd ability to reassign constants, its constants behave very similarly to, say, variables initialized with `const` pointing to an object C++ or Objective-C, or `final` in Java, `readonly` in C#, `let` in Swift (for reference types, i.e. classes but not structs), or `const` in JavaScript.

Comment: In C++ `const` infers both *immutability* and *permanence* though it is possible to have a `const` pointer to a non-`const` thing. Generally `const` is a hint to the compiler that it's okay to presume that value won't change. In Ruby you have no guarantee of immutability at all, and as for permanence, well, making something a constant is more of a promise and it could be reminded later.

Comment: @tadman: I think your answer is somewhat misleading, due to some sloppiness (I tried to come up with a better, more neutral, word, but as a non-native, nothing springs to mind, sorry) in wording: a) he is *not* modifying the constant, he is modifying the *object* the constant refers to, and b) you can't freeze constants, only objects.